# Cross-platform 3D mapping solutions

Tags: 3d, google-earth, 3d-map, worldwind, javafx

I am a new software developer who created an application at my work that continually displays content on the Google Earth desktop application using KML. My work now would like a mobile solution to my program where clients can view the app from any mobile device (mainly iOS and Android) as well as a computer.

I am looking for a viable alternative to the Google Earth API (which will be unsupported in December, 2015).I believe JavaFX has a 3D mapping library and I've read up a bit on NASA's World Wind SDK. Could anyone point me in the right direction or provide me with pros and cons of different options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ESRI** complete and less hassle. ESRI is introducing 3D across web and devices, check out ESRI Dev Summit for details. Beta is coming after 20th of next month.

**Pros**

- 3D in browser using webGL
- Have a look at caniuse.com to see if your client browser supports WebGL
  [image]
  if they do you need not to write native apps for mobile.
- In case your client mobile browsers do not support webGL ESRI is also offering 3D in android as well as IOS.
- Java API for desktops
- Can read local tiles
- IOS API

**Cons**

- For smooth workflow you might need ArcGIS desktop and Server

Have a look at **cesiumJS** https://cesiumjs.org

- WebGL 3D
- No native API for devices
- Hard to set up elevation server (at least for myself)
- For smooth operations and workflow STK Terrain Server is there
- No Java API for desktops
- Open Source
- Mapping Server will be required

Have a look at **openWebGlobe** http://www.openwebglobe.org/

- WebGL 3D
- No native API for devices
- No Java API for desktops
- Open Source
- Mapping Server will be required

  **NASA worldWind**
- Java API for desktops
- WebGL 3D
- Can work with GeoServer, Map Server and NASA WMS Server
- Support is a bit difficult
- Open Source
- Can read local tiles
- Native API for andi and IOS

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth for Android can be programmatically accessed through [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html).

This way you can open a KML in Google Earth or send a location and a zoom level to Google Earth.